# How to align two paragraphs next to each other

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I wany to two align two paragraphs next to each other.

```
Document document = new Document();

document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator line1 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0f, 100f, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("AirNet Network & Datacom Pvt Ltd \n Address :Block no 10 , Bldg no: D/6, \n RK Industrial Park. \n Mumbai -Nasik High Way, \n Thane Dist-42301 \n Tel. No.:022- 1234567890 \n Email: info@airnetnetworks.com \n Url:www.airnetnetworks.com");

Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("AirNet Network & Datacom Pvt Ltd \n Address :Block no 10 , Bldg no: D/6, \n RK Industrial Park. \n Mumbai -Nasik High Way, \n Thane Dist-42301 \n Tel. No.:022- 1234567890 \n Email: info@airnetnetworks.com \n Url:www.airnetnetworks.com");

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("G:\\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

document.Add(jpg);

document.Add(new Chunk(line1));
document.Add(paragraph);

paragraph1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

document.Add(paragraph1);

document.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Itextsharp Display data in two columns in a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471475/itextsharp-display-data-in-two-columns-in-a-single-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PdfPTable` with 2 columns and add each `Paragraph` to a cell.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
table.AddCell(paragraph);
table.AddCell(paragraph1);
document.Add(table);
```

You can also use `ColumnText`.